# Can't connect my class to my ViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

I created a menu for my app, and I have three view attached to this menu, so when I added the final 3rd view controller and created the class to control that ViewController and when I run it It won't work it shows me this error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'", but then I take out the class form the view controller and it just work! I have created new Cocoa Touch class and added it again but it won't work! :( here is where I add the class to the ViewController [image: Class]

With the other classes I have, Like the RGBViewContoller it works but only when I create a new class won't work. I have tried to unlink and link again the segue in the storyboard but it doesn't work, then I tried to do this through code and also didn't work. Heroes the code:

```
 if blueButton.selected {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(CMYKViewController, animated: true)
 }
```

Comment: Have you read the message you are receiving?  It looks like CMYKViewController is a UINavigationController instance and as the message says, you can't push a navigation controller onto another navigation controller. What is the definition of CMYKViewController?

Comment: Is my class file made with swift. @Paulw11

Comment: I know that. What I meant is "please edit your question to show the definition of this class", but from the message it seems that it is a UINavigationController subclass when it should just be a UIViewController subclass as you already have a navigation controller.

Comment: OOOh!!! Thanks!!! I am very new to swift!! sorry for that!! An thanks a lot!! @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

So my mistake (this is so everyone know in what I mess up so you don't do it again as me) was that I created a UINavigationController subclass instead of a UIViewController subclass. Hope it helps to everyone who has this problem.